# Create Update History Log Table, from JDBC - Java

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update

I need to create a history of all updates that I do on a table via JDBC. For example, I have a product table, if I make an update in the name column, need to record this change in a history table, however, only the following data; table name, name of column, and content this column before the content after the update. Through JDBC (Java).

Example table product

```
productid|name      |value
1        |computer  |1000

updated 
productid|name      |value
1        |mouse     |10

product log history
table = product
columnBefore name = computer
columnAfter name = mouse
columnBefore value = 1000
columnAfter value = 10
```

Something like that.
I do not know where to start
Any idea please?

Comment: Does the creation of the history have to be through JDBC?  Is a database trigger an option?  So your code (or any other client) does an UPDATE, and the database trigger records the change.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle (Enterprise Edition) or DB2 can do that completely automatically for your. In Postgres you can easily create audit triggers that write this information to a separate table.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g. I can develop this only java code.I can't to use Trigger. The first step I did. Compare the difference of the two objects (old, new) through the Apache libraries. Now i need to discovery how register the name of table and name of column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate, you can start with Interceptor. You can override below methods for your own purpose.

I extracted methods belong to Interceptor interface which you need for scenario.

```
/**
 * Called just before an object is initialized. The interceptor may change the <tt>state</tt>, which will
 * be propagated to the persistent object. Note that when this method is called, <tt>entity</tt> will be
 * an empty uninitialized instance of the class.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if the user modified the <tt>state</tt> in any way.
 */
public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException;

/**
 * Called when an object is detected to be dirty, during a flush. The interceptor may modify the detected
 * <tt>currentState</tt>, which will be propagated to both the database and the persistent object.
 * Note that not all flushes end in actual synchronization with the database, in which case the
 * new <tt>currentState</tt> will be propagated to the object, but not necessarily (immediately) to
 * the database. It is strongly recommended that the interceptor <b>not</b> modify the <tt>previousState</tt>.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if the user modified the <tt>currentState</tt> in any way.
 */
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException;

/**
 * Called before an object is saved. The interceptor may modify the <tt>state</tt>, which will be used for
 * the SQL <tt>INSERT</tt> and propagated to the persistent object.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if the user modified the <tt>state</tt> in any way.
 */
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException;

/**
 *  Called before an object is deleted. It is not recommended that the interceptor modify the <tt>state</tt>.
 */
public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException;

/**
 * Called before a flush
 */
public void preFlush(Iterator entities) throws CallbackException;

/**
 * Called after a flush that actually ends in execution of the SQL statements required to synchronize
 * in-memory state with the database.
 */
public void postFlush(Iterator entities) throws CallbackException;
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can not use hibernate